# Scala POST api call get an "Internal Server error" (500) as response instead of the expected error 404

Tags: scala, rest, error-handling

I have scala code below:

```
  override def createEntity(
        token: String,
    newEntity: ARequestDTO): F[Either[ErrorResponseBody, AResponseDTO]] = {
    val responseDto = for {
      _ <- ensureAddressType(addressClient.getAddressById(newEntity.addressId))
    domain = transformer.toDomain(EitherT.right(FUUID.randomFUUID[F]), newEntity, Instant.now)
      created <- repository.create(domain)
      dto     <- toResponseDTO(created)
    } yield dto
    mapErr(responseDto)
  }

  def ensureAddressType: EitherT[F, MyError, AddressResponse] => EitherT[F, MyError, AddressResponse] =
    _.ensure(RequestValidationError("Invalid address Type."))(
      _.properties.addressType === specificTypeId)


  def mapErr[E <: MyError, R](responseDto: EitherT[F, E, R]): F[Either[ErrorResponseBody, R]] =
    responseDto.leftSemiflatMap(logErr(_).map(_.toErrorResponse(entityType))).value
```

In the addressClient, I have code

```
  override def getAddressById(addressId: FUUID): EitherT[F, MyError, AddressResponse] = {
    val path = uri"$basePath/v1/address/${addressId.toString}"
    val response = baseRequest()
      .get(path)
      .response(asJson[AddressResponse])
      .sendAndRetryOnUnexpectedError()
      .map(resp =>
        resp.code.code match {
          case 200 | 201 =>
            resp.body.leftMap(forDeserializationError(addressId))
          case 404 =>
            resp.body.leftMap(error =>
              AddressClientError(s"Address not found: ${getErrorMessage(error)}"))
          case _@status =>
            resp.body.leftMap(error =>
              AddressClientError(s"Unexpected status: ${getErrorMessage(error)}"))
        })

    EitherT(response).leftSemiflatMap(logErr)
  }
```

And below is the logging error method being used.

```
  def logErr[E <: MyError](error: E)(implicit pos: Position): F[MyError] = {
    for {
      logger <- customLogger
      _      <- logger.error(s"${error.message} error-id: ${error.errorId}", error)
    } yield error
  }
```

Note that here AddressClientError extends MyError.

Here is the problem. when the addressClient.getAddressById method find the address, I got everything passed (the record was created in db). However, when no address found, it was case 404, I did get an AddressClientError exception as you can see from the code. But the whole POST call get an "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR" 500 error message responded. I suspect it was because of the `_.properties.addressType === specificTypeId` in the ensureAddressType method, because in this case, there is no AddressResponse (thus, no _.properties.addressType). Moreover, I can hit the breakpoint `_.properties.addressType === specificTypeId` in ensureAddressType method, but I can NOT hit the breakpoint at `domain = transformer.toDomain(EitherT.right(FUUID.randomFUUID[F]), newEntity, Instant.now)` in the main createEntity method. I didn't see any parsing exception printed out in the console.

Is the addressType comparison for no address found the root issue? If yes, how should I fix this (I am thinking let the ensureAddressType method checks if the input is a MyError type, throw it, if it is valid AddressResponse type, then compare with the specType)? A code example would be great. If that's not the issue, what is the problem and how to correct it?

Comment: How is `mapError` defined? What framework/lib are you using as HTTP server?

Comment: `toErrorResponse` returns 500 obviously (or throws).  Or maybe `ensureAddressType` throws when it doesn't have the address (what parameter does it get in that case? null perhaps?). In general, I don't see anything in the code you showed, that returns a 404 in any situation. Not sure where you expect to be getting it from ...